# Node.js: Using "onsubmit" instead of POST to handle form data

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, post, nodemailer

I have a simple node app that consists of a form that uses nodemailer to email its data on submit, through POST.

**HTML**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/" method="POST" class="contact-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE" required></textarea>
    <button name="send" type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

**Js (in my index.js)**

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'nodemailersampleemail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'foopassword'
    }
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    response = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        message: req.body.message
    };
    var mailClient = {
        from: 'nodemailersampleemail@gmail.com',
        to: 'nodemailersampleemail@gmail.com',
        subject: `Message from ${response.name}`,
        text: `Name: ${response.name}\nEmail: ${response.email}\nMessage:${response.message}`
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailClient, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            res.redirect("/success.html");
        }
    });
})
```

I uploaded the entire (minimized) app to github, if any clarification is needed on how my app works: https://github.com/agreyfield91/Nodemailer-Firebase-App

I'm trying to deploy this to firebase, but I was informed by support that *for some reason*, POST is not supported in the firebase SDK. I was told that I would have to use `onsubmit` in my html linked to a function in order to make my app work correctly, like so:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="contact-form" onsubmit="sendData(); return false;">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME" id="formName" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL" id="formEmail" required>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="MESSAGE" id="formMessage" required></textarea>
    <button name="send" type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to link a function properly. I have written a sendData() function, placed in my index.js file, as follows (my transporter variable is outside of the function):

```
function sendData(){
    response = {
        name: document.getElementById('formName').value,
        email: document.getElementById('formEmail').value,
        message: document.getElementById('formMessage').value
    };
    var mailClient = {
        from: 'nodemailersampleemail@gmail.com',
        to: 'nodemailersampleemail@gmail.com',
        subject: `Message from ${response.name}`,
        text: `Name: ${response.name}\nEmail: ${response.email}\nMessage:${response.message}`
    };
    transporter.sendMail(mailClient, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            res.redirect("/success.html");
        }
    });
}
```

But when I submit, the page refreshes and the form data is inserted into the url (exactly what happens when there is no function at all). Therefore, either the function isn't getting called, or what I've written inside the function doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to clarify, you realize that Firebase doesn't run your `index.js` file, correct?

Comment: Firebase support told me that I would not have use firebase functions for this functionality? The node app is supposed to work as is when deployed.

Comment: My next suggestion was going to be "Use Firebase Functions". They can accept POST requests! Firebase has no way to run server-side code besides Firebase Functions (which are really just Google Cloud Functions under the hood).

Comment: I guess I was given poor information. Would it be very complicated to transfer my current index.js to firebase functions?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be difficult! [Here's a Functions example with nodemailer](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/email-confirmation/functions/index.js). That example triggers on database writes, [here's how to trigger a function on a POST request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). You don't need to set up static file serving, you can use Firebase Hosting for that.